# Central force is planar in n-D

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

So in 3-D the differential equation 
$$\ddot{\bf{r}} = -\frac{f(r)}{m}\bf{r}$$

is shown to be planar by noting $$\bf{r} \times \dot{\bf{r}}$$

is constant. But isn't the differential equation planar (lie in a 2-d subspace) in n-D? If so, how do you show that?

Comment: Sorry should have been 3-D

Comment: to clarify, by planar i mean lie in a 2-d subspace

Comment: A more physical way to put the question: In 3D, the total angular momentum is a constant of motion for the above problem and thereby defines a plane in which the motion occurs. What about in hgher dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the motion still takes place in a plane (the plane spanned by $\mathbf{r}(0)$ and $\mathbf{\dot r}(0)$).

One way you can see it is by expanding $\mathbf{r}(t)=\mathbf{r}(0)+\mathbf{\dot r}(0)t+...$ in a series and using the differential equation to see that $\mathbf{r}^{(k)}(0)\in $ span$\{ \mathbf{r}(0), \mathbf{\dot r}(0)\}$.

The other way is the angular momentum way. To generalize cross product you use wedge product. The wedge of two vectors $x, y$ is the skew symmetric map: $x\wedge y:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $(z,w)\mapsto (z\cdot x)(w\cdot y)-(w\cdot x)(z\cdot y)$.

Then given a plane $\sigma=$ span$\{x,y\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ the complement $\sigma^\perp = \{ z\in \mathbb{R}^n : x\wedge y (z, \cdot)\equiv 0\}$.

Now you differentiate $\mathbf{r}\wedge \mathbf{\dot r}$ along a solution:

$\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{r}\wedge \mathbf{\dot r}=\mathbf{\dot r}\wedge \mathbf{\dot r}+\mathbf{r}\wedge \mathbf{\ddot r}=-\frac{f(r)}{m}\mathbf{r}\wedge \mathbf{r}=0$

so it is the same map for all $t$ so that the complement to the plane of motion is constant i.e. the plane of motion is constant.

Comment: What does that map $x\wedge y$ look like in index notation?

Comment: In an orthonormal basis it has matrix by $(x\wedge y)_{ij}=x^iy^j-x^jy^i$.

Comment: Ah, so it's just antisymmetrizing two indices (obvious, in retrospect).

Comment: Can you explain how to differentiate the wedge product?

Comment: It's just like product rule since the wedge is distributive so you can add and subtract $x(t+h)\wedge y(t)$ to  $x(t+h)\wedge y(t+h)-x(t)\wedge y(t)$ to get $x(t+h)\wedge(y(t+h)-y(t))+(x(t+h)-x(t))\wedge y(t)$ and then let $h\to 0$.